# not sure whether it wrong in basichttpbindpart or else?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have a problem when i sent a request to this web-service for getting information 
Here is my config code

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Z_SI_ADVANCE_VENDORBinding" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

and here is my code behind whick sent request to this webservice (http://www.xxxx.com)

```
    Dim epAddress As New EndpointAddress("http://www.xxxx.com")
            Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly)
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic

            Dim client As XI_ADVANCE_VENDOR.Z_SI_ADVANCE_VENDORClient = New XI_ADVANCE_VENDOR.Z_SI_ADVANCE_VENDORClient(binding, epAddress)
Dim p_output As XI_ADVANCE_VENDOR.BAPIRETURN1
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxx"
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxx"
            p_output = client.Z_SI_ADVANCE_VENDOR(param1,param2)
```

It show "Server Error" on brownser webpage when calling request is done.